# Hadoop streaming with multiple python files

Tags: python, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I have a hadoop streaming job.  This job makes use of a python script which imports another python script.  The command works fine from the command line but fails when using hadoop streaming.  Here is an example of my hadoop streaming command

```
hadoop jar $streamingJar \
    -D mapreduce.map.memory.mb=4096 \
    -files preprocess.py,parse.py \
    -input $input \
    -output $output \
    -mapper "python parse.py" \
    -reducer NONE
```

And here is the first line in parse.py

```
from preprocess import normalize_large_text, normalize_small_text
```

When I run the command through hadoop streaming I see the following output in the logs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "preprocess.py", line 1, in <module>
    from preprocess import normalize_large_text, normalize_small_text, normalize_skill_cluster
ImportError: No module named preprocess
```

My understanding is that hadoop put all the files in the same directory.  If this is true then I don't see how this could fail.  Does anyone know what's going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the scripts to the same directory and add them using files flag.

```
hadoop jar $streamingJar -D mapreduce.map.memory.mb=4096 -files python_files 
-input $input -output $output -mapper "python_files\python parse.py" -reducer NONE
```